# Positive to negative PWM converter

Tags: pwm

I am looking for a way to convert a + 24V square wave coming from a cnc controller, to -5V. The frequency of a square wave will vary from 15kHz to 35kHz.

What methods would you suggest?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Cap couple to the square wave, negative rectify and smooth the AC coming from the cap and then regulate the negative DC with a 7905.  But maybe not... How much current do you need from the -5V?

Comment: What do you have available for power? Do you already have a negative voltage available, or only positive?

Comment: I have -15V supply available. I can add a -5V smps too.

Comment: Hmm... I might have read your question wrong. Do you want to convert the +24 volt square wave into a -5 volt square wave, or do you want to convert the 24 volt square wave to -5 volts, DC?

Comment: Not DC, to -5V 15kHz square wave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your 24V pulses and strongly differentiate them with an RC high pass filter: -

[image]

Make sure they are properly differentiated like example (a) below: -

[image]

The resistor shown above needs to be connected to -2.5 volts - maybe use two equal value resistors - one to 0V and one to -5V

Reduce the amplitude to 5Vp-p (resistors and/or diode clamps can do this)

Set up a schmitt trigger running from a -5V rail and feed the clamped signal to its input. The output from the schmitt trigger will be the PWM signal you want. It needs to be a schmitt trigger so that it only changes state when a spike occurs: -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a -15V rail available, you could just use an op-amp in an inverting amplifier configuration. First, reduce the input voltage with a simple voltage divider so you get in range of the op-amp, then set the gain to give you -5.0V out.

I set it up [a quick simulation/example here](http://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%202.5000000000000002e-8%2010.200277308269968%2057%205%2050%0Av%2080%20224%2080%2080%200%202%2015000%2012%2012%200%200.5%0Ag%2080%20224%2080%20256%200%0Ar%2080%2080%20176%2080%200%20220000%0Ar%20240%2080%20336%2080%200%2047000%0Aw%20336%2080%20336%20160%200%0Aw%20240%2080%20240%20112%200%0Aw%20240%20112%20240%20144%200%0Aw%2080%20224%20176%20224%200%0Aw%20240%20176%20240%20224%200%0Aa%20240%20160%20336%20160%200%2015%20-15%201000000%0AO%20336%20160%20384%20160%200%0Ar%20176%2080%20176%20224%200%2056000%0Aw%20176%2080%20240%2080%200%0Aw%20240%20224%20176%20224%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%20290%2040%200.00009765625%200%20-1%0Ao%2010%2064%200%20290%2010%200.00009765625%201%20-1%0A) (follow the link to view it interactively) with standard 5% resistor values, which gives you -5.13V on the output rather than exactly -5.0V, but you can tweak them as necessary:

[image]